# Proving that number is least upper bound

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I am to find supremum and infimum of given set, and prove they are in fact supremum and infimum.
$$A=\lbrace x\in \Bbb{R}:x^2-5|x|+4\lt0\rbrace $$
$$\sup A = 4, \inf A = -4$$
I tried to prove it in the following way, let $\varepsilon\gt0, a\in A$,
then if $a\gt 4-\varepsilon$, $4-\varepsilon$ is no upper bound, so I can set $a$ to be equal to $4-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and therefore $4-\varepsilon$ is not upper bound what proves that 4 is least upper bound. Proof for greatest lower bound is similar.
My question is, is my proof correct?

Comment: How do you know $\exists a \in A$ such that $a > 4 - \epsilon?$

Answer (score 0):

Equivalently, $A = \{x \in \mathbf {R} | 1 < |x| < 4 \}$. This proves that $$\inf A = -4 \qquad \sup A = 4.$$